# RegEx for simple pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a logfile that contains lines like:

```
....
unit:
...
unit.integration:
....
```

I would like to run a RegEx search on the file using notepad++ that returns all lines that: start with a word with no blanks and ends with :\n. I have tried:

```
(.:\n)
```

but that gives 0 results. I have looked at:
http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/regex.html

EDIT: Updated with more specific requirements to the starting word.

Comment: `^.*:\n` ................

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to run a RegEx search ... that returns all lines that start with anything but ends with `:\n`.

The first part of the match is `:`, and because you're looking for line breaks, you'll want to match the end of the line, which is `$`.

You said you don't care about what comes before it, so don't even include it in the regex:

```
:$
```

---

Update to address edit:

> I would like to run a RegEx search ... that returns all lines that: start with a word with no blanks and ends with `:\n`.

This differs from your original post, now you want to match a "word with no blanks", however that implies that it's a single word, and doesn't contain special characters.

It seems to me that you'd like to match `unit.integration` which is two words and a separating `.` character.

If you want what you asked for ("a word with no blanks") then just prepend `^\w+` to the regex:

```
^\w+:$
```

(matches `unit:`, but not `unit.integration:`)

If, instead you want to match lines that don't contain spaces and end in `:`, then you should use `^\S+` instead:

```
^\S+$
```

(matches `unit:` and `unit.integration:`, but also matches `@#*()$&*(&:`)

The details matter, so avoid assumptions and be as explicit as possible in what you want matched.

Answer (score 1):

To get all lines that have no spaces and end in `:`, use

```
^\S+:\R
```

`\S` matches non-whitespace symbols only, and `\R` means any line break.

See screenshot:

[image]

If you plan to match the last line, too, replace `\R` with `$` (end of line or whole file metacharacter).

[image]